# JMockit: Testing Methods that override an Abstract Method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I currently have the following classes:

```
public abstract class superClass {
    abstract void abstractTest();
}

public class classForTesting extends superClass {
    @Override
    void abstractTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am currently writing a unit test (using JUnit + JMockit) for classForTesting, but I'm not sure how to test abstractTest(). I tried mocking the superclass, but I still can't call abstractTest().

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You do not mock the _class under test_. You usually mock the _dependencies_. So simply call the method `abstractTest` and test the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Seelenvirtuose. But, `abstractTest` is not visible to anybody (by design), and so it cannot be called directly. Do you have suggestions on how to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want abstractTest to be public, then test the method that calls abstractTest. I also changed the class names to start with a capital letter.

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    abstract void abstractTest();
}

public class ClassForTesting extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    void abstractTest() {
        ...
    }

    public void publicMethod() {
        abstractTest() 
    }

}
```

And now test publicMethod:

```
public class PublicTest {

    private ClassForTesting classForTesting;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        classForTesting = ClassForTesting();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        classForTesting.publicMethod();
        ...
    }
}
```